# Can we rename related list "Notes & Attachment"?

Tags: related-list

In my project, we have a requirement that related list "Notes and Attachments" to be renamed to something else.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you will have to use Visualforce. Here's an example of how to override the header:

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
  <apex:relatedList list="notesandattachments">
    <apex:facet name="header">
      <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputText value="My Notes"></apex:outputText>
        <apex:form>
          <apex:commandButton value="A Note" action="URL_OR_ACTION_METHOD"></apex:commandButton>
        </apex:form>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:facet>
  </apex:relatedList>
</apex:page>
```